# "clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files" in Xcode C++ Eigen Library

Tags: xcode, eigen

After I got hard time to include Eigen Library using a tutorial in 
compiling this file produce the following message:
"clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files in Xcode C++ Eigen Library"

Comment: What does the clang command look like that it's complaining about?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
    MatrixXd m(2,2);
    m(0,0) = 3;
    m(1,0) = 2.5;
    m(0,1) = -1;
    m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
    std::cout << m << std::endl;   
}

Comment: Above is what i am trying to compile. I am sorry i couldn't write it in the "code form", because i could not

Comment: That's your code but I asked about the command that compiles your code.

Comment: I am using Xcode on Mac OS. So after i write the code i run it using "play sign". I am very thankful for your concern